# UIAutomation won't work in Windows Server (VPS) if I am not connected via RDP

Tags: windows, vps, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, microsoft-ui-automation

I have script which uses mircrosoft's UIAutomation to automate an application. The script is inside a VPS running Windows Server 2012. The script works perfectly while I am connected to the VPS via Remote Desktop (RDP).

When I am not connected, the script seems to be stuck on `SetFocus` for a object... which leads me to believe that the script needs a Display/Screen/Session in order to work... but I am not sure if it is possible to do it while I am not connected to the VPS.

I can see 2 possible solutions here, either modify the script in someway to work in this environment or make the VPS have a virtual desktop while I am not connected (this solution might be more related to Server Fault rather than StackOverflow).

I am very confused, thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: You should probably provide an MCVE. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did not own the server or have administrative privillages at that time, and I was using an uncommon programming language via a library, so I was not sure about the raw calls to UIAutomation either. For those reasons I was unable to provide an MCV example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to workaround the issue by actually connecting to the server to itself (to `127.0.0.1`) via RDP so that it will always have an active RDP session for the automation script to run.

I am not happy with the results but it works... I cannot give clear instructions on how you would need to modify the settings in Windows to allow RDP connections from self, it was a one big trial and error process, I have to modify some policies in the Group Policy Editor and then some stuff that I don't remember.

There is another downside to this, a Windows server will allow 2 simultaneous connections to it but by using this method we are reserving a slot so only 1 connection at a given time is possible, something to be aware of.